# Java servlet redirect

Tags: java, http, redirect, servlets, forward

So, i want to forward/redirect a user to /user/dashboard.html if he is already loged in or to /login.html if he is not loged in ONLY when he accesses the root url (in this case http://localhost:8080/myapp).

I made this servlet but it goes in a loop no matter what address i access:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/")
public class WelcomeController extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(authenticated()) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/user/dashboard.html");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);      
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURL()+"/login.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Access controls are more naturally implemented in a filter. That way, you do not clutter the application logic with a different concern.

Comment: How can i " don't let it invoke itself again in an infinite loop" ?

Comment: I checked those and it's not a solution to my problem. I tested the solutions and i still get a loop